# Private MobileDevice.framework not discovered from clang anymore with the -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks switch

Tags: objective-c, macos, clang

I am working with the mobiledevice device app from https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice.

But since the latest Mac OSX update 10.13.02 (17C88) I can't compile the mobiledevice app anymore because clang complains about not finding the private "MobileDevice" framework searched in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice
$ cd mobiledevice 
$ make
clang ... -o mobiledevice ... -framework MobileDevice -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -DMOBILEDEVICE_CLI_VERSION=\"2.0.0\" -DMOBILEDEVICE_CLI_REVISION=\"8134c5e7edd97bf718490eaadb3639bda276e596\" cli.m commands.m device.m get_app_prop.m get_bundle_id.m get_device_prop.m help.m install_app.m invalid_usage.m list_app_props.m list_apps.m list_device_props.m list_devices.m tunnel.m uninstall_app.m version.m
ld: framework not found MobileDevice
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I can see that the framework still exists in the directory /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks.

It seems that clang is filtering out the -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks switch.

Any hints how to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question I found out that copying the MobileDevice.framework to another location (.) and setting the framework path to that location makes clang recognise the private framework.
So its a clear indicator for me that clang has filtered out the -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks switch.

```
$ cp -a /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework ./MobileDevice.framework/
$ clang .. -o mobiledevice ... -framework MobileDevice -F.
```

gives no "framework not found" error anymore

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not work for me on Big Sur. I've found not supplying /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks but instead /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks solves it.